# Convert numeric(32,0) to DATETIME in SSIS job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

My data source is giving me a column of type `numeric(32,0)` that is the epoch value, and I want to convert that to a `DATETIME` in my database.  I've got a Derived Column transform and for the expression I tried to do this:

```sql
DATEADD("SECOND", CAST([Last Modified Date] AS BIGINT) / 1000, (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1970-01-01")
```

But it's giving me parsing errors.  Can someone help me with the proper syntax for this please? If I don't quote `"SECOND"` then it immediately tells me that SECOND is not an input column.

Even though the input is the `numeric(32,0)` type they're all integer values, such as 1564371486110.

Answer (score 1):

I do not immediately understand your cast and divide by 1000.

SSMS

```
select datediff(ss,  '1970-01-01 00:00:00', getdate())
1564069434
```

Expression

```
dateadd("SS", 1564069434, (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1970-01-01 00:00:00")
2019-07-25 15:51:17.763
```

Edit - I am going to assume you're dividing for milliseconds on the epoch time.

Derived Column Transformation Editor - Expression

```
 DATEADD("SS",(DT_UI8)SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,32)epochtime,1,LEN(TRIM((DT_WSTR,32)epochtime)) - 3),(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Comment: Yes, I've got milliseconds :)  When I hardcode a number that'll work, but I can't get it to work with my input column. The parser gives me an error saying it might contain an invalid token, and incomplete token, or an invalid element.

Comment: @Gargoyle could try bringing it in / casting it as a string, substring off the milliseconds instead of dividing, and then cast that to a bigint/something like DT_UI8. Can try it myself later and update if it works. What is an example value you have btw, can you add it to the question?

Comment: 1564371486110 is an example.

Comment: @Gargoyle  Try - DATEADD("SS",(DT_UI8)SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,32)epochtime,1,LEN(TRIM((DT_WSTR,32)epochcolumnthatisnumeric32)) - 3),(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1970-01-01 00:00:00")